# Get corners of quadrilateral from outline

Tags: python, geometry

I have the coordinates of the outline of a (convex) quadrilateral. These are stored as a list in the form of `outline = [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ..., (xn,yn)]`, though this can be changed/modified in any way convenient. I want to find the vertices of the quadrilateral.

[Image of plotted outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEa4h.png)

So far, I've considered using linear programming to find the coordinates. However, because of the possible granularity, this wouldn't work. Also, it would probably require heuristics to implement, which I want to avoid for robustness.

Obviously, one can find two coordinates by doing the highest and lowest y-value, but from there, I'm rather stuck at where to go next.

How can I get the coordinates of the corners?

Note - I've tagged this python, as that's the language that I'm using for my project, though a description of an algorithmic approach would be a much-appreciated answer as well.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far as this is no coding service but a help site. Also providing some input data will ease helping you.

Comment: @areop-enap Because the data is rather large, is there a convention on Stack Overflow for how to upload such files? Also, for code, I've tried coding the linear programming I've mentioned in my question, although I realized that I would need to use a bunch of heuristics, and I've explicitly stated why I don't want to go down that route. The other code in my project is generating the data, which probably wouldn't be very interesting in the context of the problem.

Comment: How big is n? (Firstly, if it is not too big, then you can just post some code defining `outline`; secondly, that changes the possible approaches). How noisy are your data (outline)? Are points of `outline` ordered?

Comment: n is usually somewhere around 10^4. Outline won't be too noisy - it'll only have the points in the rectangle (I've already done clustering, etc), though the edge might be slightly jagged

Answer (score 1):

If data points have exact coordinates (exactly lie on quad sides), you can get some extremal point (topmost for example), then sort other points by angle, choose the smallest angle, аnd get the farthest point with this angle - next vertex, then repeat with new vertex and so on - it is like convex hull building with **gift wrapping algorithm**.

If points positions are not perfect, consider approximation of sides with straight lines using **Hough transform**

Some libraries like OpenCV contain Hough transform inplementations, as well as convex hull ones.